# Laravel 8: Cannot use a scalar value as an array after using pluck()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-collection, laravelcollective

I'm trying to send an array of my Model `Role` to Blade like this:

```
public function create()
{
    $roles = Role::pluck('name','id');
    return view('admin.users.create', compact(['roles']));
}
```

And on the Blade, I added this:

```
<div class="form-group">
   {!! Form::label('roles', 'Role:') !!}
   {!! Form::text('roles[]', $roles, null, ['multiple' => 'multiple', 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
```

Now I get this error:

> **ErrorException** Cannot use a scalar value as an array on
> create.blade.php

However, when I add `{{ dd($roles) }}`, I get this as result:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1155 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    1 => "Manual User"
  ]
}
```

So what is going wrong here ? How can I fix this issue ?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are not supposed to get 2 columns of values using the method `->pluck()`, pluck is used to retrieve a single column of value (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#retrieving-a-list-of-column-values). If you want to retrieve 2 columns from the model, you could try using the `->select()` method instead:

```
$roles = Role::select('id', 'name')->get();
```

Comment: I tried that and still shows me the same error!

Comment: the 2nd parameter is the eventual key column that is assigned to each value: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck

Comment: Another issue you have is this line `{!! Form::text('roles[]', $roles, null, ['multiple' => 'multiple', 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}`, the first parameter of `Form::text()` should be the field name, you should not use an initialized array for the first parameter

Comment: @Jacky.S Yes, that was the point, it should be `Form::select`

Comment: I am glad you got the problem solved, if my answer helps, please accept it, thank you